# shared_ptr delete object inside struct

Tags: c++, struct, shared-ptr

I am beginner with c++ and losted with pointer

I want to delete pointer after use to release memory

```
shared_ptr<target> target_ptr(new targ(url));

struct targ
{targ(const std::string& p_url) : url(p_url) {}
std::string                         url;...

...
map<string, shared_ptr<target> >::iterator it;

for (it = targets.begin(); it != targets.end() ; ++it)
{
    delete target;//????? it doesn't work
}
```

Thanks

Comment: i forget map<string, shared_ptr<target> >    targets;

Comment: You are trying to delete a type

Comment: `targets.clear();` and let smart pointer does the cleaning.

Comment: not delete target; but delete it;

Comment: You can edit your post instead of adding comments about those corrections.

Comment: When you use `shared_ptr` it takes care of `delete`. You shouldn't do that manually. Anyway, to get more specific answers than that general observation you should post **complete code** that readers can just copy and compile.

Comment: ok thanks i try your targets.clear();

Answer (score 2):

`target` is the name of a type. You cannot `delete target;`.

You also cannot delete a smart pointer. Only pointer types can be deleted, and smart pointers - despite their name - are class types.

> not delete target; but delete it;

You also cannot delete `it`. `it` is an iterator; not a pointer. It points refers to the smart pointer that refers to the object; it doesn't refer to the object itself.

You also must not delete a pointer owned by a smart pointer. The pointed object is automatically destroyed when all shared pointers pointing to it are destroyed (or pointed somewhere else). So, if the only copy of the shared pointer is in that map, then simply removing the pointer from the map will cause the pointed object to be destroyed.

You apparently try to remove all shared objects. This can be easily achieved by removing all smart pointers from the map: `targets.clear()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::shared_ptr`'s `reset()` member function:

```
for (auto it = targets.begin(); it != targets.end() ; ++it)
{
    it->second.reset();
}
```

or:

```
for (auto& p: targets)
    p.second.reset();
```

Doing so will call `delete` on the pointed `target` object **if** no other `std::shared_ptr` is taking part in the ownership of that object.

Comment: Thanks for all, i found the solution, my string is very big 20000 character

Comment: void replaceAll(string& str, const string& from, const string& to) {
    if(from.empty())
        return;
    string wsRet;
    wsRet.reserve(str.length());
    size_t start_pos = 0, pos;
    while((pos = str.find(from, start_pos)) != string::npos) {
        wsRet += str.substr(start_pos, pos - start_pos);
        wsRet += to;
        pos += from.length();
        start_pos = pos;
    }
    wsRet += str.substr(start_pos);
    str.swap(wsRet); // faster than str = wsRet;
}